# Multiple controllers for a single template view

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-controller, angularjs-ng-route

In angularjs, I have already made view templates consisting of multiple controllers. Now while routing can we specify multiple controllers to one template or there should be only one controller for a template?

If you do not understand this question please specify in comment.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the answer is no. You can't use multiple controller in router state, however you can add multiple controller in template HTML. 
Alternate solution is using dynamic template in a directive. If you use the dynamic template, then for each router state you can use multiple controller in different different HTML template.

```
app.directive('View', function () {
 return {
  restrict: 'E', 
  scope: {
    templateUrl: "=",
  },
  replace: true,
  template:     "<div ng-include = 'templateUrl'></div>",
 };
})
```

Then in directive you can do that by just passing different template url.
And in your template you can use different different controller.

In html you can use directive as follows:

```
<view templateUrl = "templateUrl0.html"> <view>
<view templateUrl = "templateUrl1.html"> <view>
```

Finally, in the `templateUrl0.html` and `templateUrl1.html`, you can add `Controller0` `Controller1`.

Comment: I simply passed just one controller used in the partial template and its working. My issue is resolved, though i would find out how it is working.